# PHP contact form: cyrillic letter not being sent if it is not short

Tags: php, email

I am making a contact form on my website and, trying to submit it, I get two outcomes:
**1.** I wrote email in english, and, no matter how long it is, it is sent perfectly fine.
**2.** I wrote it in russian. If it is shorter than about 10 symbols - I get the email and it is even correctly rendered. If it is longer than that - I just never get this email!

my html header includes:

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma">
```

my form:

```
  <form method="post" action="a.php">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

my a.php:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];

$header = "From: Hi";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";

$subject = "This is letter";
$email_to = "***my email***";
$message = "Name: $name."

mail($email_to, $subject, $message, $header);

?>
```

Please help, I don't have a clue on why is that and how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe because the lines are [longer than 70 characters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) that way. Check the return value of the mail call - and your error log (put the output of the php error log in the question if reading it doesn't immediately answer your question).

Comment: @AD7six, they are not longer than 70 characters. I don't get any errors. Post returns "Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily", but it also returns it when message is sent.

Comment: Your code work correctly on my server.

Comment: Try $subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';

Comment: @coronator1999, yes, it worked. Thank you a lot, I figured out all my contact forms I ever made were broken (never tested them with long russian messages). Could you write this as an answer? (preferably with explanation on what was going on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';
```

What `base64_encode()` does is best explained in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php):

`base64_encode()` is designed to make binary data survive transport through transport layers that are not 8-bit clean, such as mail bodies.